# Single quotes on Quarkus examples, error or not?

Tags: quarkus

I've seen this example in the Quarkus guide, and the single quotes gives error on Windows SO. Are they to indicate what exactly that should be written or is it that it should be written literally like that?

Example on Quarkus Guide

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible that it is written for a Linux environment. Apparently, Windows handles single quotes differently. It is possible that double quotes (") would work.

You also need to have access to this `quarkus` command. So if it tells you that the command cannot be found, that might be the issue.

Comment: Yes, with double quotes or without them works on Windows, but this example confuses the user.

Comment: Very well might be, but that won't be changed by this Stack Overflow thread. These commands are meant typed/copied into the terminal 1:1. That they do not work for windows will not be intentional. They just picked 1 of 3 variants which work for Linux, which is precisely the variant not working on Windows. That is most certainly not desired and an oversight. You'd need to contact the Quarkus team to get it changed, as I don't see any way to submit a change suggestion for the guides.

Comment: I'll do it. Thank you for your answer.